# Binding and DecodePixelWidth property

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

Does any one know why binding doesn't work for DecodePixelWidth property? When I set it through xml - all works fine - I see scaled image. When I use binding for that - image doesn't scaled.

```
<Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="2292" Stretch="None">
    <Image.Source>
         <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Src}" DecodePixelWidth="{Binding DecodePixelWidth}"  />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>

    public int DecodePixelWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return _decodePixelWidth;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _decodePixelWidth)
            {
                _decodePixelWidth = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DecodePixelWidth");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and I've found this solution http://diegoparolin-codeplus.blogspot.it/2014/09/set-decodepixelheight-property-binding.html that it works for me.

In my MVVM WPF application, I want to resize a bitmap image with values stored in app.config. Therefore, for doing this I’ve tried to bind the Image.Height property and the BitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight directly to my ViewModel, like in this way:

In app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>   
  <appSettings>   
    <add key="DocumentsToBeFiledImageHeight" value="240"/>
    <add key="DocumentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeight" value="240"/>
  </appSettings> 
</configuration>
```

Then in my ViewModel I’ve added these properties

```
private int _documentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeight;
public int DocumentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeight
{
  get { return _documentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeight; }
  set
  {
    if (value != _documentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeight)
    {
      _documentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeight = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(DocumentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeightPropertyName);
    }
  }
}

private double _documentsToBeFiledImageHeight;
public double DocumentsToBeFiledImageHeight
{
  get { return _documentsToBeFiledImageHeight; }
  set
  {
    if (value != _documentsToBeFiledImageHeight)
    {
      _documentsToBeFiledImageHeight = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(DocumentsToBeFiledImageHeightPropertyName);
    }
  }
}
```

and this code

DocumentsToBeFiledImageHeight = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentsToBeFiledImageHeight"]);

DocumentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeight = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeight"]);

Then in the XAML I’ve added this code

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.DocumentsToBeFiledImageHeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> 
   <Image.Source>
     <BitmapImage DecodePixelHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.DocumentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        UriSource="{Binding Path=FullName}" />
   </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Unfortunately it doesn’t work, it seems that the DecodePixelHeight property is not set correctly.
Therefore, I’ve tried to recover the value directly from app.config. I’ve added these parameters in the user setting section in my app.config file

```
<userSettings>
  <Agest.AO.Client.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="DocumentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeight" serializeAs="String">
      <value>240</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="DocumentsToBeFiledImageHeight" serializeAs="String">
      <value>240</value>
    </setting>
  </Agest.AO.Client.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

and I’ve changed the XAML code in this way

```
xmlns:localme="clr-namespace:Agest.AO.Client.Properties" 

<Image Grid.Row="0" Height="{Binding Source={x:Static localme:Settings.Default}, Path=DocumentsToBeFiledImageHeight, Mode=OneWay}">
  <Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage DecodePixelHeight="{Binding Source={x:Static localme:Settings.Default}, Path=DocumentsToBeFiledImageDecodePixelHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
            UriSource="{Binding Path=FullName}" />
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Now it works and I’m able to set values directly in the configuration file.

Regards!